# TinyMCE - Apply "text-align" to span

Tags: html, css, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm currently using the WYSIWYG editor tinyMCE in a CMS for clients to create their own text for adverts.
This means that on the front end, everything they put in the textarea will appear in an `<a>` tag.

I'm trying to make sure the semantics are correct so I have disabled the `forced_root_block` option to stop `<p>` tags being used, but the text-align options wrap the selected text/element in a `<div style="text-align:center">` which I don't want.

Is there a way I can force tinyMCE to use `<span style="display:block; text-align:center">` instead to achieve the same result.

Here is my current tinyMCE init

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#advertText',
        menubar: false,
        width: <?php echo $selectedSizeWidth ?>,
        height: <?php echo $selectedSizeHeight ?>,
        forced_root_block: false,
        resize: false,
        invalid_elements: 'div',
        plugins: [
            'textcolor colorpicker fontawesome'
        ],
        fontsize_formats: "14px 16px 18px 20px 24px 36px",
        toolbar: 'bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, |, fontsizeselect, |, forecolor, backcolor, |, alignleft, aligncenter, alignright, alignjustify, |, outdent, indent, |, fontawesome'
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Managed to find a solution myself eventually by editing the default style formats in the tinyMCE init.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/format-custom/

Below is the code I added to my tinyMCE init to override the standard styles.
This means that the selected text element (eg. a span) will be wrapped in a span with the styles `display: block` and the relevant `text-align` property.

```
formats: {
            alignleft: {selector: 'span,em,i,b,strong', block: 'span', styles: {display: 'block', 'text-align':'left'}},
            aligncenter: {selector: 'span,em,i,b,strong', block: 'span', styles: {display: 'block', 'text-align':'center'}},
            alignright: {selector: 'span,em,i,b,strong', block: 'span', styles: {display: 'block', 'text-align':'right'}},
            alignfull: {selector: 'span,em,i,b,strong', block: 'span', styles: {display: 'block', 'text-align':'full'}}
        }
```

Comment: instead of **alignfull** use **alignjustify**

Comment: I think the link is broken?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is not too late for you. I had the same problem, because I load the content into p tags. The first answer is close to the solution. But you have to define the inline tag that will be used for the align. Complete the first answer's code with this: inline: 'span', like this:

```
formats: {
    alignleft: {selector: 'span,em,i,b,strong', inline: 'span', block: 'span', styles: {display: 'block', 'text-align':'left'}},
    aligncenter: {selector: 'span,em,i,b,strong', inline: 'span', block: 'span', styles: {display: 'block', 'text-align':'center'}},
    alignright: {selector: 'span,em,i,b,strong', inline: 'span', block: 'span', styles: {display: 'block', 'text-align':'right'}},
    alignfull: {selector: 'span,em,i,b,strong', inline: 'span', block: 'span', styles: {display: 'block', 'text-align':'full'}}
```

},

Comment: instead of **alignfull** use **alignjustify**